# Creacting react app why install the node.js and npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

My terminal is stuck on that and still processing for creating the environment of react app
node.js(version: 18) all specifications included

I installed the node.js and npm for the creating react app and its run-time environment.
All requirements are to be added but not responded to by terminal
Is it important for react app? But why?[description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRrt1.png)

Comment: You need to run npx create-react-app first